# How to setup read replica for Aurora Serverless

Tags: amazon-aurora, aws-aurora-serverless

I have global user base spread globally. If I use AWS Aurora MySQL Serveless DB, and select Multi-AZ support, how to use read replica closer to the user for RO queries.
To be more specific, Primary DB will in London.
London User -> London App Server --> London DB (for read)
Tokyo user -> Tokyo App Server --> Tokyo DB (for read)

London/Tokyo user -> London/Tokyo App Server --> London DB (for write)
All I want to understand is how to force App SErver to connect to the nearest read replica.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is an option to create a read replica for Aurora MySQL Serverless DB. Please refer to the official setup documentation [here](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless.create.html).

I think your only option is to use Aurora Global Database that spans multiple AWS regions. Read more [here](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-global-database.html).